# How to achieve text over semitransparent image on a button

Tags: android

I'm trying to write text on top of the image on my ImageButton.

I've been looking around on the internet and I know that you can't set ImageButtons text. Everybody suggests that I use a Button instead and set its background, but they ignore the fact that if I do that, the button itself is going to become a clickable image(I want an image to be drawn on top of a android button image, not just an image by itself). Is there any other way to do that? I also would like to avoid having FrameLayouts if possible.

Comment: framelayout does indeed seem like the easiest way of doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FramLayout is by far the best way to do this. This code should get it done

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="somethingHere" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" 
        android:background="somethingHere"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: As I mentioned, when using normal button and setting the background to the image, creates a disgusting clickable image, it doesn't look like a button at all. ImageButton is the way to go here. Also I tried to avoid using FrameLayout and I was hoping for something else, but there doesn't seem to be any other solution, so this has to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a subclass of `android.view.Button`, and override its `onDraw(Canvas)` method to draw the image before calling `super.onDraw` to let the superclass draw the text and border.